# Styling 'fieldset' with rounded borders on iphone interface builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa, coding-style

I'm extremely new to objective-c and iOS development and was just looking for advice at how best to tackle this type of styling. Basically these types of field sets (see screenshot) appear everywhere with rounded edges and borders between rows.

Is there some type of functionality in interface builder to handle this already or would I be looking at using background image(s) and then adding the form parts above that?

[image: screen shot]

iOS objective-c iphone fieldset styling rounded edges rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). They are a *major* interface element (maybe *the* major element) in iPhone apps. You can set up a table view to have rows that act like buttons, or information-entry fields, as here, or really in any way that you care to write the code for. See the [Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) for discussion of their use.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I think I finally hit the right combo of google keywords to find some stuff for myself too. Looks like I want a custom UITableViewCell like this (kind of):

Comment: haha it's funny seeing this question again after finishing my app and understanding cocoa a little better. ;)